# Displaying Unicode symbols in Windows XP. Maybe web font?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, cross-browser, google-webfonts

I want to display the unicode [U+1F589](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f589/index.htm) () in a web page, but in Windows XP I can't make it work. Installing fonts or something in the OS is not an option, because it is complicated for the user; I need something that works out of the box.

I try with Google fonts, but no. Is there any web font that has support for symbols? Is there a way to force the browser to fallback to a font with that character?

Comment: Just to be sure: you know Windows XP has not been supported by Microsoft for years now, right? (almost two years now, [support ended April 8, 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help)) You're asking about how to do something on an obsolete operating system.

Comment: I can't be less interested in Microsoft support. Not supportive it is not equivalent to obsolete. Here (Argentina) a high percentage of PCs uses XP (currently, 13,21% according to statcounter).

http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-os-AR-monthly-201502-201602

Comment: you can, and clearly are. Your target audience is still on windows XP. That is an important detail to add to your post, similar to someone asking about how to do something in Ubuntu v8. You're asking about a technology that's been abandoned by the people that made it, and you want to make sure people don't recommend "upgrade" as the most obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely intent on doing it this way, then you can host a font that supports the character yourself. [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) and [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) do, and can be loaded in via something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'xyz-font-name';
  src: url('/path/to/font.ttf');
}
```

You can then use `font-family: 'xyz-font-name'` when required. All that said, keep in mind these fonts are not small in terms of size. If you're after something that is less difficult to work with, then simply hosting an equivalent image might be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for a more than complete answer! I was thinking also in create my own font, but as you said, I probably incline myself to use css sprites (or maybe use jQuery UI).